# Discontinous line when plotting

Tags: plotting, dataset

If I have the following data:

```
data={{-2.77815, 1.}, {-1., 0.926106}, {-0.69897, 
  0.798319}, {-0.522879, {0.695556}}, {-0.221849, 0.501958}, {0., 
  0.368454}, {Log[2]/Log[10], {0.22527}}, {Log[3]/Log[10], 
  0.165922}, {Log[6]/Log[10], 0.100537}, {1, 0.0723884}, {Log[20]/
  Log[10], 0.0487545}, {Log[30]/Log[10], 0.0393246}, {Log[50]/Log[10],
   0.0301417}, {Log[60]/Log[10], 
  0.0274377}, {2, {0.0210421}}, {Log[200]/Log[10], 
  0.0145785}, {Log[300]/Log[10], 0.0117054}, {Log[500]/Log[10], 
  0.00882057}, {Log[600]/Log[10], {0.00797757}}, {Log[800]/
  Log[10], {0.00674971}}, {3, 0.0059353}};
```

How do I display this data as a line with no "discontinous line" between data?. In other words, if I use `ListLinePlot[data]` I get the following plot with discontinous line:

[image]

**EDIT**

I think the issue has to do with the fact that there are some data in the y axis that contain an extra `{}` and I do not know how to remove only for those with the extra `{}`

Comment: `data = data /. x_List?(Length[#] == 1 &) :> x[[1]];`

Comment: Or, `data /. {z_} -> z`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
newdata = Flatten /@ data;
ListLinePlot[newdata]
```

[image]